# Karma, Jasmine, Uncaught Error: <toHaveBeenCalledTimes> : Expected a spy, but got Function without test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, spy

Sorry in advance for my bad english..

I am testing my application with Karma and Jasmine and I have a really strange error. 
I have 9 tests and when I run tests it seems that karma finds a 10th test. And Karma returns me a Jamsine error :
**Uncaught Error:  : Expected a spy, but got Function**

That is strange is : when I launch my test in debug mode. All is good. 
More strange is that I have 3 files. Error occured just when I execute 3 files at the same times. With 2 files all is good ^^ ...

Have you already seen this error?

I will give you two screens. First no debug mode. Second debug mode. And I will give you my code.

**[No Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLXBh.png)**.png


**[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW3EP.png)**.png

**activate.controller.js**

```
describe('userActivateCtrl', function() {
beforeEach(module('Betizy'));

var $controller;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _ngToast_, _$filter_, _userService_, _navigationService_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
    ngToast = _ngToast_;
    $filter = _$filter_;
    userService = _userService_;
    navigationService = _navigationService_;
}));

describe('at its launch', function () {
    it('add an info toast in the toastList to say at the user what to do.', function () {
        var controller = $controller('userActivateCtrl', {
        });

        expect(ngToast.messages.length).toBe(1);
        expect(ngToast.messages[0].className).toBe('info');
        expect(ngToast.messages[0].content).toBe($filter('translate')('user.activate.message'));
    })
});

describe('for a valid registration', function () {
    it("call method from userService when activation is called by the click on activation button.", function () {
        var fakeHttpPromise = {
            then: function () {}
        };
        var controller = $controller('userActivateCtrl', {
        });
        controller.userActivateForm = {$valid: true};
        spyOn(userService, 'activate').and.returnValue(fakeHttpPromise);
        spyOn(navigationService, 'toIndex').and.returnValue(fakeHttpPromise);

        controller.activate();

        expect(userService.activate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

        setTimeout(function () {
            expect(navigationService.toIndex).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            done();
        })
    })
});

describe('for an invalid activation form', function () {
    it("does nothing.", function () {
        var controller = $controller('userActivateCtrl', {
        });
        var fakeHttpPromise = {
            then: function () {}
        };
        controller.userActivateForm = {$valid: false};
        spyOn(userService, 'activate').and.returnValue(fakeHttpPromise);
        ngToast.dismiss();
        controller.activate();
        expect(ngToast.messages.length).toBe(0);
        expect(userService.activate).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
});
});
```

**login.controller.js**

```
describe('userLoginCtrl', function() {

beforeEach(module('Betizy'));



beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$stateParams_, _ngToast_, _$filter_) {
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $stateParams = _$stateParams_;
    ngToast = _ngToast_;
    $filter = _$filter_;
}));

describe('at its launch', function () {
    it('add an info toast in the toastList to say at the user what to do.', function () {
        var controller = $controller('userLoginCtrl', {});

        expect(ngToast.messages.length).toBe(1);
        expect(ngToast.messages[0].className).toBe('info');
        expect(ngToast.messages[0].content).toBe($filter('translate')('user.login.message'));
    });

    it('add an danger toast in the toastList if user was mistaken during authentication.', function () {
        $stateParams.state = "error";

        var controller = $controller('userLoginCtrl', {});
        expect(ngToast.messages.length).toBe(2);
        expect(ngToast.messages[0].className).toBe('danger');
        expect(ngToast.messages[0].content).toBe($filter('translate')('user.login.error'));
    });
});
});
```

**register.controller.js**

```
describe('userRegisterCtrl', function(){
beforeEach(module('Betizy'));

var $controller;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _userService_, _ngToast_, _$filter_, _navigationService_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
    userService = _userService_;
    ngToast = _ngToast_;
    $filter = _$filter_;
    navigationService = _navigationService_;
}));

describe('at its launch', function () {
   it('add an info toast in the toastList to say at the user what to do.', function () {
       var controller = $controller('userRegisterCtrl', {
       });

       expect(ngToast.messages.length).toBe(1);
       expect(ngToast.messages[0].className).toBe('info');
       expect(ngToast.messages[0].content).toBe($filter('translate')('user.register.message'));
   })
});

describe('for a valid registration', function () {
    it("call method from userService when register is called by the click on register button.", function () {
        var fakeHttpPromise = {
            then: function () {}
        };
        var controller = $controller('userRegisterCtrl', {
        });
        controller.userRegisterForm = {$valid: true};
        spyOn(userService, 'register').and.returnValue(fakeHttpPromise);
        spyOn(navigationService, 'toIndex').and.returnValue(fakeHttpPromise);

        controller.register();

        expect(userService.register).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

        setTimeout(function () {
            expect(navigationService.toIndex).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            done();
        })
    })
});

describe('for an invalid registration with invalid mail adress', function () {
    it("add a danger toast in the toastList for an incorrect mail adress pattern.", function () {
        var controller = $controller('userRegisterCtrl', {
        });
        controller.userRegisterForm = {$error: {email: true}, $valid: false};
        ngToast.dismiss();
        controller.register();
        expect(ngToast.messages.length).toBe(1);
        expect(ngToast.messages[0].className).toBe('danger');
        expect(ngToast.messages[0].content).toBe($filter('translate')('user.register.error.email.pattern'));
    })
});

describe('for an invalid registration and a valid mail adress', function () {
    it("does nothing.", function () {
        var controller = $controller('userRegisterCtrl', {
        });
        var fakeHttpPromise = {
            then: function () {}
        };
        controller.userRegisterForm = {$error: {email: false}, $valid: false};
        spyOn(userService, 'register').and.returnValue(fakeHttpPromise);
        ngToast.dismiss();
        controller.register();
        expect(ngToast.messages.length).toBe(0);
        expect(userService.register).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
});
});
```

Thank you in advance for you help I will become crazy !

**EDIT : 1**
When I debug in chrome with inspector I see that :

> SUCCESS userActivateCtrl for a valid registration call method from userService when activation is called by the click on activation button.

And just after I see that :

> Uncaught Error:  : Expected a spy, but got Function. 
>   Usage: expect().toHaveBeenCalledTimes() 
>       at compare (jasmine.js:3302) at Expectation.toHaveBeenCalledTimes (jasmine.js:1543)
>       at activate.controller.js:41

So question is why it executes that whereas test passed just before?

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: which test cases fails?

Comment: As you can see on two screens, no test failed but it seems in the debug console of my browser that it executes twice activate.controller.js en the 2nd test.